# ASP.NET: Custom layout for Wizard Control

Tags: asp.net, layout, wizard

Is there any way to change the default layout for Wizard Control?

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of templates that come with various parts, such as the headertemplate, and various navigation templates that allow you to customise it to a certain extent.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx

I suppose it depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Place the following `<LayoutTemplate>` tag inside of your `<asp:Wizard>` tag.

```
<asp:Wizard ...>
     <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="headPlaceHolder">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="headerPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </div>

        <div class="sidePlaceHolder">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="sideBarPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="stepPlaceHolder">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="WizardStepPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="navPlaceHolder">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="navigationPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>

     ...
     ...
</asp:Wizard>
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx